# If conditional statement Error: unexpected '}' in " }"

Tags: r, if-statement

```
rankhospital <- function(state, outcome, num = "best"){
      ## Read outcome data
      data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
      hospital <- data.frame(data[,2], #name 
                             data[,7], #state
                             data[,11], #heart attack
                             data[,17], # heart failure
                             data[,23], stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #pneumonia
      colnames(hospital) <- c("name", "state", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
      ## Check that state and outcome are valid
      if (!state %in% hospital[, "state"]) { stop('invalid state')} 
      else if (!outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")){ stop('invalid outcome')}
      else if (is.character(num)){
        if (num == "best") {
          chosen_state <- hospital[which(hospital[, "state"] == state), ] #select the state
          chosen_outcome <- chosen_state[ , outcome] #select the outcome from the state
          best_outcome <- chosen_state[which(chosen_outcome == min(chosen_outcome, na.rm = TRUE)),]["name"]
          best_hospital <- best_outcome[order(best_outcome)][ , "name"] #sort
          best_hospital
        } 
        else (num == "worst") {
          chosen_state <- hospital[which(hospital[, "state"] == state), ] #select the state
          chosen_outcome <- chosen_state[ , outcome] #select the outcome from the state
          best_outcome <- chosen_state[which(chosen_outcome == max(chosen_outcome, na.rm = TRUE)),]["name"]
          best_hospital <- best_outcome[order(best_outcome)][ , "name"] #sort
          best_hospital
        } 
      else (is.numeric(num)) {
        if (num =< length(hospital$name){
          chosen_state <- hospital[which(hospital[, "state"] == state), ] #select the state
          chosen_outcome <- as.numeric(chosen_state[ , outcome]) #select the outcome from the state
          chosen_state[which(sort(chosen_outcome)) == num, ][,"name"]

       } 
        else (num > length(hospital$name) { stop('NA')}

     } 

    }
```

When i run the code, it throws " Error: unexpected '}' in "}" " where 
else (num == "worst") part, so if i change this if from else, it'll go down and throws me an error again at else (is.numeric(num)). What have i done it wrong with this code? I thought If statement goes like this

1. If
2. else if
3. else if
4. else

Also, you can add addition If/else statement inside of them like how i used..Maybe not since it throws me an error, can anyone see what's wrong with it and tell me how to solve?

Comment: You are using the `if`/`else` syntax incorrectly; `else` catches all cases not satisfied by `if`. So there is no more explicit condition for `else`. For example: `a <- 3; if (a == 4) cat("not 3") else cat("3")`

Comment: what do you mean? could you point out using my code above? i'm new to programming and if/else syntax really confuses me..

Comment: It's incorrect in every single line containing `else`; for example line `else (is.numeric(num)) {` should be `} else {` and so on (also note the brackets)...

Comment: Thank you, i now understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else if` and `else` have to be on the same line as the end of the `if` expression, you can't have a newline between them. You can express this neatly using braces e.g.:

```
x = 3

# This doesn't work
if (x == 2) { print("x is 2") }
else if (x == 3) { print("x is 3") }
else { print("x is something else")}

# This does, else if is on the same line as the end of the
#   if expression
if (x == 2) { 
    print("x is 2") 
} else if (x == 3) { 
    print("x is 3") 
} else { print("x is something else")}
```

Comment: Yes, that's one issue of OP's code; the other being the erroneous condition statement after `else`.

Comment: There can be multiple lines before an `else` when you postpone typing the closing "}" .